# difference NFS proto and mountproto

Tags: rhel, nfs, udp, nfsv4, protocols

in RHEL 8.8 when I am trying to test NFS tcp versus udp and versions 3 versus 4.0, 4.1 and 4.2, I observe on my nfs client a `mountproto=` in addition to `proto=` when typing `mount`.  What is the significance of this and what does it mean?

Should I be able to, in RHEL 8.8, have NFS operating showing specifically `vers=3` and `proto=udp` on the nfs client?

What does it mean, on the nfs client, when I see `proto=tcp` and `mountproto=udp` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In older NFS versions (v2 and v3) there are two distinct RPC services handled by separate software: the "MOUNT" protocol that's used only to obtain the initial filesystem handles from rpc.mountd, and the "NFS" protocol that's used for everything else.

So the `mountproto=` option defines the transport used to access rpc.mountd whenever you mount an NFSv3 filesystem. It has no effect on performance, only compatibility (older mountd did not support TCP). NFSv4 doesn't have `mountproto=` anymore because the mount-related operations have been integrated into the core protocol.

Meanwhile `proto=` defines the protocol used to transfer file data (the actual NFS operations.) NFSv3 supports UDP, so yes, proto=udp,vers=3 is possible, but keep in mind the caution message in the manual page – NFS via UDP over a Gigabit or faster connection *risks data corruption*, and the faster your connection is, the higher risk of corruption. NFSv4 supports TCP and RDMA only – it doesn't support UDP anymore.

Comment: thanks!  consider putting your last sentence in bold in a separate paragraph.

Comment: will `vers=3 proto=udp` **over 100gb mellanox infiniband** be faster than `tcp` and/or `rdma` and by how much?  How/when would data corruption be recognized?

Comment: No, I rather doubt it would be. Why do you expect it would be faster than rdma?

Comment: @u1686_grawity `udp` can be [faster](http://imoverclocked.blogspot.com/2011/04/nfs-performance-tcp-vs-udp.html) than `tcp` on a robust network without congestions. It's not that I advocate using `udp` for NFS, definitely not.

Comment: experimenting in rhel 8.8, over infiniband, I am seeing no real speed difference between, udp, tcp, rdma, sync or async, vers=3 to 4.2., for a single file copy of 40gb. confused.  i thought udp was always inherently faster than tcp (1x vs back-and-fortth)

Comment: @ron: Do you mean TCP acknowledgements and their absence in UDP? Not sure what you mean by "1x" there.

Comment: yes, *A key difference between TCP and UDP is speed, as TCP is comparatively slower than UDP. Overall, UDP is a much faster, simpler, and efficient protocol, however, retransmission of lost data packets is only possible with TCP*.  https://www.lifesize.com/blog/tcp-vs-udp/.  So UDP should always be faster than TCP?

Comment: i want to know the realisticly user observable speed difference possible, of simple large file transfers over 100gb infiniband, `vers=3 proto=udp` versus `vers=4.2 proto=rdma` and what are the limiting factors in play

Comment: "Pure" UDP does not have retransmissions or such; but retransmissions are 1) only relevant if you have packet loss, 2) unavoidable if you want the service to _work,_ and so most "UDP-based" protocols implement _their own_ retransmissions anyway – nobody uses "pure" UDP; e.g. NFS has several options controlling UDP request retransmission. Similarly, pure UDP doesn't have packet acknowledgements or flow control, but those features are required for reliable transfer (if you try to send more packets than the receiver can accept, they'll just be dropped), so NFS has its own flow control anyway.

Answer (score 3):

From `man 5 nfs`:

```
       mountproto=netid
                      The  transport  the NFS client uses to transmit requests
                      to the NFS server's mountd service when performing  this
                      mount  request,  and  when  later  unmounting this mount
                      point.
...
       proto=netid    The  netid determines the transport that is used to com-
                      municate with the NFS  server.   Available  options  are
                      udp,  udp6,  tcp,  tcp6, and rdma.  Those which end in 6
                      use IPv6 addresses and are only available if support for
                      TI-RPC is built in. Others use IPv4 addresses.
```

In other words, the `mountproto` only determines the protocol for the `mount` and `umount` requests, and `proto` determines the protocol of the rest of the NFS operations once the area is mounted.

For NFSv3, you can use `proto=tcp` and `mountproto=udp`.

However, NFSv4 only supports tcp, it will not work with udp.

```
                      All  NFS  version 4 servers are required to support TCP,
                      so if this mount option is not specified, the  NFS  ver-
                      sion  4  client  uses  the  TCP  protocol.  Refer to the
                      TRANSPORT METHODS section for more details.
```

And for NFSv4, `mountproto` has no effect.

```
   Using the mountproto mount option
       This section applies only to NFS version 2 and version 3  mounts  since
       NFS version 4 does not use a separate protocol for mount requests.
```

Comment: More than that, NFSv4 *does not have* a separate mount RPC protocol anymore (the relevant calls are part of the core protocol).